# don't rewrite static css/js/img files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get my htaccess file not to rewrite my static files (js/css/images).

This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ public/index.php?url=$1
```

How do I rewrite it?

Comment: Why would your .htaccess will rewrite your static file if you don't want to rewrite it? Just clear your .htaccess and it wouldn't be rewritten. Also you said in your question _not to rewrite_ and _How do I rewrite it_. Can you please explain a little bit what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1
```

All requests to not existing files which doesn't end with listed extensions (case nonsensitive match) are rewritten to `public/index.php` passing the current URL as `url=` GET argument

Answer (score 6):

This only works for the one line below it. So if you have many RewriteRules it could help to use something like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(php|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me. Also it's better to add `eot, ttf, woff, woff2 and svg` to this list

Answer (score 2):

for posterity.

Maybe my rules will be useful

> `\www\.htaccess`

```
#file: \www\.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js|html?|png|gif|jpg|jpe?g|svg|xls.?|pdf|docx?|eot|ttf|woff2?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*\.[css|js|html?|png|gif|jpg|jpe?g|svg|xls.?|pdf|docx?|eot|ttf|woff2?]+) public/$1?a [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|html?|png|gif|jpg|jpe?g|svg|xls.?|pdf|docx?|eot|ttf|woff2?) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*\.[css|js|html?|png|gif|jpg|jpe?g|svg|xls.?|pdf|docx?|eot|ttf|woff2?]+) public/$1 [QSA,L]

#RUN TEST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|html?|png|gif|jpe?g|svg|xls.?|pdf|docx?|eot|ttf|woff2?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?REQUEST_FILENAME=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&date=$1&REQUEST_URI=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
#END TEST

RewriteRule . index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 index.php?error=404
```

> `\www\index.php`

```
<?php
// file: /www/index.php
 var_dump($_GET);
```

> `\www\app\.htaccess`

```
#file: \www\app\.htaccess`

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../_%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

> `\www\public\.htaccess`

```
#file: \www\public\.htacces`
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}&rewrite=$1 [QSA,L]
```

> `/www/public/index.php`

```
<?php
// file: /www/public/index.php
 var_dump($_GET, __DIR__);
```