# .htaccess : include a subdirectory within URL (only for certain files)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a seemingly simple `RewriteCond`, however, I've been chasing my tail trying to find a solution. I have searched the docs ([here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html), [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)), in addition to [this similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473129/redirect-cssjsimgfonts-folder-using-htaccess) and this [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433703/dont-rewrite-static-css-js-img-files), but haven't been able to solve the issue.

## FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
/config
/public
  /js
  /css
  index.php
/src
  /controllers
    /ajax
  /models
  /views
```

## AIM

If the URL is too www.example.com, or any .js, .css, .jng files, include 'public' in the URL.

```
wwww.example.com -> www.example.com/public/index.php
www.example.com/js/main.js -> www.example.com/public/js/main.js
```

However, I wish to write a `RewriteCond` that exempts any other URL request.

```
wwww.example.com/src/controllers/ajax/doSomething.php -> NO CHANGE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.js$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.css$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.jng$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/public
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```